# Attempt to install/upgrade using apt fails due to not being able to remove spacewalk

Tags: apt, 20.04, uninstall

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.

Running and `apt install` command returns an error, posted below. Too my understand of the error apt tries to remove `apt-transport-spacewalk` but fails.

How can I successfully remove this `apt-transport-spacewalk` program? Or, instead, how can I stop `apt` from trying to uninstall it, so that I can install the programs I need?

**Stack trace**:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-spacewalk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-spacewalk is already the newest version (1.0.6-4.1).
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-transport-spacewalk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 326 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 92.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py:540: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 25
  email_re = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9_\+\-\.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)')
(Reading database ... 150063 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apt-transport-spacewalk (1.0.6-4.1) ...
mv: cannot stat '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50spacewalk': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package apt-transport-spacewalk (--remove):
 installed apt-transport-spacewalk package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-transport-spacewalk
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: 1) Create the missing file: `touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50spacewalk`. 2) Let apt remove the package. Then 3) Fix the `326 not upgraded`. Finally, 4) Reinstall the package.

Comment: @user535733 This fixed it. Thank you!